# How to lag data based on two columns in r

Tags: r

I have data like below

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"),
             quarter = c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","1","2","3","4"),
             rate = c(0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.09,0.08,0.07,0.06),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to create a lag variable based on year and quarter columns, the final output looks like below

```
output <- data.frame(year = c("2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"),
             quarter = c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","1","2","3","4"),
             rate = c(0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.09,0.08,0.07,0.06),
             lag_rate = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.03, 0.01,0.02, "NA"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How should I code this into R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete the missing information for each `year` and `quarter` and then use `lag` to get previous years' quarter value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  tidyr::complete(year  = seq(min(year), max(year)), quarter = 1:4) %>%
  arrange(year, quarter) %>%
  group_by(quarter) %>%
  mutate(lag_rate = lag(rate))

#    year quarter  rate lag_rate
#   <int>   <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  2005       1  0.05    NA   
# 2  2005       2  0.06    NA   
# 3  2005       3  0.07    NA   
# 4  2005       4  0.08    NA   
# 5  2006       1  0.03     0.05
# 6  2006       2  0.01     0.06
# 7  2006       3  0.02     0.07
# 8  2006       4 NA        0.08
# 9  2007       1  0.09     0.03
#10  2007       2  0.08     0.01
#11  2007       3  0.07     0.02
#12  2007       4  0.06    NA
```

Note that this will have more rows than your original data if you have missing observations. In case, if you want the original number of rows back you can add `filter(!is.na(rate))`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df1 %>% complete(year,quarter) %>% mutate(lag_rate = lag(rate, 4))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   year  quarter  rate lag_rate
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2005  1        0.05    NA   
 2 2005  2        0.06    NA   
 3 2005  3        0.07    NA   
 4 2005  4        0.08    NA   
 5 2006  1        0.03     0.05
 6 2006  2        0.01     0.06
 7 2006  3        0.02     0.07
 8 2006  4       NA        0.08
 9 2007  1        0.09     0.03
10 2007  2        0.08     0.01
11 2007  3        0.07     0.02
12 2007  4        0.06    NA
```

Data used:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(year = c("2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", 
"2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"), quarter = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4"), rate = c(0.05, 
0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
>
```